# How to sum the numbers in cells if there is text?

Tags: sum, formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Guys please help with such a problem. Need to sum numeric cells with text inside? He gave an example of the table, like 1 + 3 + 8 = 12. Is there any way to solve this? Thank !

[image]

Comment: What does "1h3m" return? 13? or 1 and 3?

Comment: Please don't put additional information in the comments, [edit] your question. Did you take the [tour] and read "[ask]" already? (At least your image is visible, well done!)

Comment: What other characters are there beside the decimal digits? Are there floating point numbers to consider?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I edited the question, is my problem clearer now?

Comment: Do you need a single formula or are allowed to use more cells? I mean, there are regular expression functions that can extract the digits, and then you could use the `value` function, and the `sum` function. -- Oh, and who is "he"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>(i assume the task is to sum the numerical components of the cell content, ignoring everything else)</sup>

In LibreOffice Calc, you can do this using a combination of three built-in functions:

- **[REGEX()](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id831542233029549)**  to eliminate non-numeric content;
- **[VALUE()](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3150802)** to get the numerical value of the REGEX() result; and
- **[SUMPRODUCT()](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3163286)** to sum up the calculated numerical values in one step.

<sup>(I've set the "g" (global) flag as 4th argument of the REGEX() function. In your example, it isn't required, but the calculation would fail with more than one non-numerical character)</sup>

1. Use REGEX to eliminate non-numerical stuff:

   [image: Usage of VALUE() and REGEX() functions in LibreOffice Calc]

   <sup>**A2**: Input value (string); **B2**: calculated numerical value; **C2**: Formula used to calculate B2</sup>
2. Use SUMPRODUCT() and VALUE() to sum the remaining numerical values:

   [image: Combination of SUMPRODUCT(), VALUE() and REGEX()]

   <sup>**A2:C2**: Input values (strings or numbers); **D2**: calculated numerical value; **E2**: Formula used to calculate D2</sup>

Here's a detailed overview over the formula:

[image: Function wizard showing an analysis of the formula]

Comment: This is exactly what I ment, but I was too busy.

Comment: There is no need for array entering. `SUMPRODUCT` will handle restrictions from implicit intersection natively. Otherwise you might as well have used `SUM`. Upvoted though for a nice and thorough answer =)

Comment: @JvdV - thanks a lot, you're right - i will remove the array formula stuff since it's misleading...

Answer (score 1):

The way you show it, it can't be done. There's no arithmetic which will add numbers to text and get a number as a result.

If the `h` and the `t` stand for something, maybe you could use column headings to explain?

[image: Example]

Another possibility might be to concatenate things somehow, but I don't think that's what you mean.

[image: Example]

(Am using Libreoffice.)

Comment: Thanks for editing, @thebusybee :)  Although after seeing the other answers, it's pretty clear I misunderstood what Geferson was looking for...

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking integers, it seems like you could simply use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-(REGEX(A1:C1;"\d+";;"g")))
```

And maybe to include negative integers:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-(REGEX(A1:C1;"-?\d+";;"g")))
```

---

[image]

Comment: That's nice, much easier than my solution! What's the meaning of the minus sign before the inner (2nd level) round brackets (just before `(REGEX...`)?

Comment: @tohuwawohu, it's a remnant from the [doubly unary](https://exceljet.net/the-double-negative-in-excel-formulas) I use in Excel. Since it's my first ever attempt with `LibreOffice` I couldn't find a way to evaluate a formula but the point is the same but instead of two, it's just a single negative. If you would try `{INDEX(-(REGEX(A1:C1;"\d+";;"g"),1)}` you will see it return the numeric translation of the text returned through `REGEX`. I hope it makes sense. I guess you could sum it up as the equivalent of just puting `1*(REGEX(A1:C1;"\d+";;"g")` (or `VALUE` for that part)

Comment: Also, don't think it's a easier solution necessarily. Yours would handle addition of decimals too. In that way yours is "easier", hence why I explicitly mentioned **integers** in my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in EXCEL

Separator `;`

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2; {"h";" "}; ""))+VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2; {"t";" "}; ""))+C2
```

Separator `,`

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, {"h"," "}, ""))+VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2, {"t"," "}, ""))+C2
```